# PHP query in a view will cause website error

Tags: views, database

I'm using a global PHP query in a View to find out the count of membership users.
The first query, that extracts the total number of users from the database works fine, but when I use the *WHERE* clause in a query for a comparison with a string, I received a website error like in the image attached below.

This is the query:

```
<?php
$count_users_premium = db_query('SELECT COUNT(license_id) FROM {commerce_license} WHERE state="active"')->fetchField();
print $count_users_premium;
?>
```

So, if I want to use *WHERE some_number=3*, it will work, but comparison with a string didn't work. (Drupal 8 version)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly insert values into queries in Drupal. They need to be escaped. You would want something like this:

```
$count_users_premium = db_query('SELECT COUNT(license_id) FROM {commerce_license} WHERE state=:active', [':active' => 'active'])->fetchField();
```

Comment: You're a hero! Thank you!!!